# Pricing: Are push notifications really free?

Tags: parse-platform

According to the [parse.com pricing page](https://www.parse.com/plans), push notifications are free up to 1 million unique recipients.

API calls are free up to 30 requests / second.

I want to make sure there is no catch here.

An example will clarify: I have 100K subscribed users.  I will send weekly push notifications to them.  In a month, that will be 4 push "blasts" with 100K recipients each.  Is this covered by the free tier?  Would this count as 4 API calls, 400K API calls, or some other amount?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the price of a service.

Comment: @PascalCuoq I would agree - however the OP asks about API calls - so aside from the pricing aspect of it I think it is a legitimate question.

Comment: @Adjit “aside from the pricing aspect of it”, there is no question. The question is about the pricing.

Comment: @PascalCuoq True - I guess the OP could reword the question. I was just taking a look at the example

Comment: The question is about policy.  The terms of the pricing policy are unclear (at least to me).  I figured that since this was posted to parse.com tag only, and that parse.com support and knowledgeable users answer here, it would be on topic.  If it's not, do what you need to do...

Comment: More of investment opportunity than a reason for close-vote.  That's a lot of users on a free infrastructure.

Comment: @danh, indeed.  hence my question and my fear that somehow i am misunderstanding....

Comment: One could make a litigious argument that this fails as an SO question, but as a practical matter, will future parse.com developers find it useful and use a good answer to guide how they program for parse?  I think so.  I'd vote to leave it open.  (and hope I can buy a piece of the business).

Answer (score 4):

100k users is 1/10 the advertised unique recipient limit, so that should be okay.

Remember that there's a 10sec timeout, too.  So the only way to blast 100k pushes within the free-tier resource limits is to create a scheduled job that spends about 2 hours (that's a safe rate of 15 req/sec) doing pushes and writing state so you can pick up later where you left off.

Assuming there's no hidden gotcha (you'll probably need to discover those empirically), I think the only gotcha in plain sight is the fact that the free tier allows only one (1) scheduled job.  Any other long-running processing -- and there are bound to be some on 100k users -- are going to have to share the job, making the what-should-this-single-job-work-on-now logic pretty complex.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Clarification: Did you see Adjit's answer?  He quotes where the docs say that a request to send a push to multiple recipients counts as only 1 request.  Are you saying that such an API call would probably execute for longer than 10s when sending to 100K recipients?  Also, rather than use the parse scheduled job, would anything stop me from running the job on my own machine, and enforcing the rate limiting with a custom script?

Comment: Not saying that 1 request would take 10 seconds, but at 30/sec max, 300 will.  So you'll need to space them out.  I suggest 2hrs to give you some headroom to read and write state.  I don't know of any constraint from parse that would prevent you running your own server, as long as it throttles requests to < 30/sec.  That could be a good alternative to a single background job.

Comment: @danh I have answered numerous different question regarding API requests, and I've been trying to get people to understand that Parses API limits are maxed out on a per minute basis as opposed to per second. Read their second FAQ here https://www.parse.com/plans/faq that's  a big difference to me, hence my mission to get the word out. I personally have a game app that uses over 30/ps because of its intent, but it wont receive limit errors until 1800/pm. You can do a lot in a minute concerning parse so keeping the API requests mentality away from per second gives you more room to breath.

Comment: @soulshined - Thanks.  Yes.  I'll try to remember to point that out as well.

Answer (score 3):

You should take a look at the **FAQ** for Parse.com:

https://www.parse.com/plans/faq

> **What is considered an API request?**
>
> Anytime you make a network call to
>   Parse on behalf of your app using one of the Parse SDKs or REST API,
>   it counts as an API request. This does include things like queries,
>   saves, logins, amongst other kinds of requests. ***It also includes
>   requests to send push notifications, although this is seen as a single
>   request regardless of how many recipients are targeted.*** Serving Parse
>   files counts as an API request, including static assets served from
>   Parse Hosting. Analytics requests do have a special exemption. You can
>   send us your analytics events any time without being limited by your
>   app's request limit.

Comment: Thanks.  I did see that.  Everything I read in the docs suggests it would be free.  But since it has a "too good to be true" feel, I was looking for confirmation that I'm not missing something...

Comment: I would say you are in the clear. However, I would also test it to make sure - like push 31 notifications in 1 second. You could also set up a javascript `setTimeout` for every second to only push 30 notifications / second and just run through your list of app users. It would take around an hour to send out all notifications - but from a marketing standpoint that shouldn't be too detrimental